# how do i sort an arraylist of array using comparater?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist of bean. Each bean contains multiple elements. There is one element in bean 'userid'. This userid can be valid phone number, valid email, invalid phone number or invalid email id. I want to show valid phone numbers on top den valid email ids then invalid phone numbers and then invalid password. How do i do this using comparater

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you done *any* research? If so, can you show the results?

Comment: Please provide us with what have you done so far, then only an answer can thought of.

Comment: here what you want http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: in fact a don't need to sort the list. I just want to re-arrange it. After re-arrange valid phone numbers should come on top den valid emails den invalid phone and invalid email. eg: <br/>981234567 <br/>9712345677 <br/> 1234567890 <br/> asdfg@gmail.com <br/>abcd@mail.com <br/> 3456789567 <br/> 9876543200 <br/>zxcvbn@qwer.com

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Comparator` and sort them by Id of your `bean` class using the `Collections.sort`

```
ArrayList<bean> data= new ArrayList<bean>();


    Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<bean>() {

        public int compare(bean s, bean s2) {
            return s.getId() - s2.getId(); //this will sort your arrayList in ascending order
        }
    });
```

The above code will sort your `ArrayList` of bean base on your `id` in ascending order